# $\sin 2x - \sin^2x = 20\sin x + 10 \cos x - 1$ with $90\leq x \leq 180$

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing

> solve $\sin2x - \sin^2x = 20\sin x + 10 \cos x - 1$ with $90\leq x \leq 180$

I arrived at $2\sin x \cos x + \cos^2 x = 20\sin x + 10 \cos x $ and resulting in $(2\sin x + \cos x)(\cos x - 10) = 0$ but i am stuck at finding the x satisfying $(2\sin x + \cos x) = 0$. Maybe i was wrong somewhere. What should i do?

Comment: Is $x$ given in degrees rather than radius? That would explain the numbers $90$ and $180$.

Comment: How did you arrive at that answer? If you add details about the steps you took, then we will be more likely to be able to spot where you may have gone wrong

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's enough to solve the following equation:
$$2\sin{x}+\cos{x}=0.$$
Now, if $\cos{x}=0,$ so $\sin{x}=0,$ which gives $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=0,$ which is a contradiction.

Thus, it's $$\tan{x}=-\frac{1}{2}$$ or
$$x=-\arctan\frac{1}{2}+180^{\circ}k,$$ where $k\in\mathbb Z,$ which gives
$$x=180^{\circ}-\arctan\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: Can down-voter explain us, why did you do it?